# When field value is empty, it says it's too short! (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm going to try to explain this as best as I can.  Okay, so here is my code:

```
function validation() {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
    var at = "@";
    var dot = ".";
    var lat = email.indexOf(at);
    var lstr = email.length;
    var ldot = email.indexOf(dot);

    var success = true;

    if (name == null || name == "") {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "I want to know who you are!";
    }

    if (document.contact.name.value.length <= 5) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "Full name, please!";
    }

    if (email.indexOf(at) == -1 || email.indexOf(at) == 0 || email.indexOf(at) == lstr) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "That's not an email!";
    }

    if (email == null || email == "") {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Give me your email!";
    }

    if (document.contact.email.value.length <= 8) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Email is too short!";
    }

    if (subject == null || subject == "") {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "I need a subject!";
    }

    if (document.contact.subject.value.length <= 5) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "A longer subject would be nice.";
    }

    if (message == null || message == "") {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "Don't forget your message!";
    }

    if (document.contact.message.value.length <= 30) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "Your message is too concise!";
    }

    return success;

}
```

My problem is that even when the value of the id is empty, it still says it's too short.  For example, when I click the send button, it says the field for name is too short, even if it's empty.  I thought I stated it that if name == "" (which is empty), say "I want to know who you are!".  But now, it justs says, "Full name please" which is suppost to be displayed if the value of name is <= 5... NOT when it's empty.  Get what I'm saying?

Comment: Use `else if`s. That way only one of the errors will be `innerHTML`ed. And instead of setting success `false` in every block, keep it false initially.

Answer (score 2):

Make it into an `elseif` instead of having two separate independent conditions:

```
if(name == null || name == "") {
success = false;
  document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "I want to know who you are!";
}
else if(document.contact.name.value.length <= 5) {
 success = false;
document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "Full name, please!";  
}
```

Comment: Tha tag says `javascript != php`

Comment: You're referencing to a PHP doc while we're talking about JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for looking at PHP and JS at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

You are mentioning all the conditions related to a field as only `if` but actually you need to mention them as `if.. else` or `if... else if.. else` statements.

If you mention only if statements, then it will execute all the related codes to a field and atlast it will show the latter value which you are assigning to `innerHTML` which is always "*Email is too short!*" in your "Email field" condition.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I should say, if name == "" do this, else if name <=5 do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your fix code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form validation</title>
<script>
function validation() {

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value.trim();
    var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value.trim();
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value.trim();
    var at = "@";
    var dot = ".";
    var lat = email.indexOf(at);
    var lstr = email.length;
    var ldot = email.indexOf(dot);

    var success = true;

    if(name == null || (name.length)==0) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "I want to know who you are!";
    }else{          
        document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(name.length > 1 && document.contact.name.value.length < 5) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "Full name, please!";  
    }

    if(email == null || email.length==0) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Give me your email!";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "";
    }       

    if(email.length > 1 && document.contact.email.value.length <= 8){
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "Email is too short!";     
    }

    if(email.length > 8 && email.indexOf(at) == -1 || email.indexOf(at) == 0 || email.indexOf(at) == lstr){
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("email-error").innerHTML = "That's not an email!";
    }   

    if(subject == null || subject.length==0) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "I need a subject!";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(subject.length > 0 && document.contact.subject.value.length <= 5){
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("subject-error").innerHTML = "A longer subject would be nice.";  
    }

    if(message == null || message.length==0) {
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "Don't forget your message!";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "";
    }

    if(message.length > 0 && document.contact.message.value.length <= 30){
        success = false;
        document.getElementById("message-error").innerHTML = "Your message is too concise!"; 
    }

    return success;

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" name='contact'>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=''/>
    <span id="name-error"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=''/>
    <span id="email-error"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value=''/>
    <span id="subject-error"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" value=''/>
    <span id="message-error"></span>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Send" onclick='return validation();'>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neerajkumarsingh/W7dWN/)